# How to extract the month from a date response in Google Forms using Apps Script

Tags: date, google-apps-script, extract, google-forms

I have a Google form that asks the user to input the date of the meeting. I want to use their response and extract the month of their date so that I can use that to access a subfolder based on month and year within which to store their Google form file uploads.

I want to know which Google Apps Script function to use to extract the month.

Answer (score 0):

**Getting Year and Month from form date entry**

I have my date question appearing in column8 for my form so that's why it's e.values[7]

```
function onMyFormSubmit(e) {
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));//useful for debugging
  const [y,m] = [new Date(e.values[7]).getFullYear(),new Date(e.values[7]).getMonth() + 1];//months begin with zero in date object so add one
  Logger.log('Year: %d Month: %d',y,m);
}
```

- [google-apps-script reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)
- [javascript reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)
- [Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)
- [Javascript Date Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)